# No factories configured while using Jetty 7 embedded + Myfaces 1.2

Tags: testing, jetty, myfaces, embedded-jetty

I am using an embedded version of jetty 7 to load a web application using Apache MyFaces 1.2 in a junit 4 test class on the advice from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284774/can-we-use-junit-for-automated-integration-testing).

While running the test i get this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions!
If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml.
A typical config looks like this;

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This application works fine with tomcat, weblogic and even oc4j!

How can i get this to work with jetty?

Comment: There is an issue at codehaus http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the myfaces-impl jar which had the .tld file inside the WEB-INF/lib directory.